# Performing operations in dataframe and lists in R

Tags: r, list, vector, dataframe

Here is a data snippet from a csv file. The list contains names of cities where John traveled and hours he stayed there.

```
sno   City   hours stayed
1   London     5
2   London     4
3   Dubai     2
4   Mumbai     8
5   Sydney     16
6   Sydney     16
7   Dubai     2
8   London     8
9   London     9
10   Paris     17
```

I need help in calculating the following:

1. Name of most visited city by john (by number of visits);
2. Name of City where he stayed for longest (cumulative stay) hour;
3. Name of city where he stayed for longest time in a single visit , how many hours and which city;
4. average number of hours in each of the city (cumulative hours).

Comment: Please learn how to [format your question text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 library(dplyr)
 df <- tbl_df(df)
```

I. Name of most visited city by john (by number of visits)

```
 df %>%
 select(City) %>% 
 table() %>% 
 sort(decreasing=T)

 #  London  Dubai Sydney Mumbai  Paris 
 #       4      2      2      1      1

 # 2nd alternative
 df %>%
 group_by(City) %>%
 summarise(n=n()) %>%
 arrange(desc(n))

 # Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

 #     City     n
 #   (fctr) (int)
 # 1 London     4
 # 2  Dubai     2
 # 3 Sydney     2
 # 4 Mumbai     1
 # 5  Paris     1
```

II. Name of City where he stayed for longest (cumulative stay) hour

```
 df %>%
 group_by(City) %>%
 mutate(cumsum(hours_stayed)) %>% 
 arrange(City)

 # Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
 # Groups: City [5]

 #     sno   City hours_stayed cumsum(hours_stayed)
 #    (int) (fctr)        (int)                (int)
 # 1      3  Dubai            2                    2
 # 2      7  Dubai            2                    4
 # 3      1 London            5                    5
 # 4      2 London            4                    9
 # 5      8 London            8                   17
 # 6      9 London            9                   26
 # 7      4 Mumbai            8                    8
 # 8     10  Paris           17                   17
 # 9      5 Sydney           16                   16
 # 10     6 Sydney           16                   32



 df %>%
 group_by(City) %>%
 summarise(sum(cumsum(hours_stayed)))

 # Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

 #    City sum(cumsum(hours_stayed))
 #   (fctr)                     (int)
 # 1  Dubai                         6
 # 2 London                        57
 # 3 Mumbai                         8
 # 4  Paris                        17
 # 5 Sydney                        48
```

III. Name of city where he stayed for longest time in a single visit , how many hours and which city

```
 df %>%
 group_by(City) %>%
 summarise(max(hours_stayed))

 # Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

 #     City max(hours_stayed)
 #   (fctr)             (int)
 # 1  Dubai                 2
 # 2 London                 9
 # 3 Mumbai                 8
 # 4  Paris                17
 # 5 Sydney                16
```

IV. Average number of hours in each of the city (cumulative hours)

```
 df %>%
 group_by(City) %>%
 summarise(sum(mean(hours_stayed)))

 # Source: local data frame [5 x 2]

 #     City sum(mean(hours_stayed))
 #   (fctr)                   (dbl)
 # 1  Dubai                     2.0
 # 2 London                     6.5
 # 3 Mumbai                     8.0
 # 4  Paris                    17.0
 # 5 Sydney                    16.0
```

Comment: Thanks Sowmya. while I always prefer base R code I found dplyr library very useful. thank for sharing this info.

Comment: Basic R is good, but if you want all data manipulation tasks in an organized manner, then that would be done using functions of `dplyr` package. To check list of functions in `dplyr` package, you can type `ls("package:dplyr")`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` to get a `summarize` output by 'City' and then get the 'City' that have max value from the output.  There may be many ways to go, but `dplyr` is the easiest to understand and simple.  Besides, for big datasets, it 
will be efficient to use `dplyr/data.table`.

```
library(dplyr)
res <- df1 %>% 
          group_by(City) %>% 
          summarise(n = n(),
                    totalHours = sum(hours_stayed),
                    maxHours = max(hours_stayed), 
                    meanHours = mean(hours_stayed))
res %>%   
          summarise_each(funs(City[which.max(.)]), -City)
#      n totalHours maxHours meanHours
#   <chr>      <chr>    <chr>     <chr>
#1 London     Sydney    Paris     Paris
```

The average number of activity for each city can be got from 'res' itself

```
res %>% 
    select(City, meanHours)
#    City meanHours
#   <chr>     <dbl>
#1  Dubai       2.0
#2 London       6.5
#3 Mumbai       8.0
#4  Paris      17.0
#5 Sydney      16.0
```

NOTE:

1) In case of ties for the maximum number of visits or other cases, this selects the first max value.

2) We can do all the operations in a single pipe flow instead of calling functions again and again.

---

Another efficient option is `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
res2 <- setDT(df1)[, .(n = .N, totalHours = sum(hours_stayed,
                        maxHours = max(hours_stayed),
                        meanHours = mean(hours_stayed))
                 ,  by =  City]
```

Answer (score 1):

These are too many questions at one go, solutions of which is quite easy and can be done in base R.

```
#Name of most visited city by john (by number of visits)

which.max(table(df$City))
#London 
# 2 

#Name of City where he stayed for longest (cumulative stay) hour
aggdata = aggregate(hoursstayed ~ City, df, sum)
aggdata[which.max(aggdata$hoursstayed), ]

#    City hoursstayed
#5 Sydney          32

#Name of city where he stayed for longest time in a single visit ,
# how many hours and which city

df[which.max(df$hoursstayed), ]

#   sno  City hoursstayed
#10  10  Paris          17

#average number of hours in each of the city (cumulative hours)

aggregate(hoursstayed ~ City, df, mean)

#   City hoursstayed
#1  Dubai         2.0
#2 London         6.5
#3 Mumbai         8.0
#4  Paris        17.0
#5 Sydney        16.0
```

Comment: @AbhayM you are welcome Abhay. If you think this answers yours question you can accept (by clicking on the check next to vote) this answer.